# Crystal Reports 2016: using "startswith" function for multiple parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

Per my supervisor's request, I have to modify a report in a way that two parameters that allows multiple selections have to be moved to the select expert section. Since the parameters are allowing the multiple selections, I am trying to use the "startswith" function like this.

```
({Command.incident_type} startswith {?IncidentType})
and
({Command.property_use} startswith {?PropertyUse})
```

I've used the startswith function before, but not for more than one parameter. The report is showing data, but it's not showing all the data. It is omitting one or two fields and I am not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something as follows.  I have not tested it so not sure if it will work but I would possibly do it this way for a similar request.

```
{Command.incident_type} like "{?IncidentType}*" and 
{Command.property_use} like "{?PropertyUse}*"
```

Example
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will test it and let you know!

Comment: Tested it and sorry to report that it did not work.

Comment: Did you put it in the record expert and set the type to formula? I just tested a local example on my PC and it seemed to work - returned all items that start with a certain word/phrase.

Comment: Yes, I put it in the record expert section. I'm not sure what you mean by setting the type, though.

Comment: I added an example image in my answer above.  Have a look this this link, explains how to use the LIKE wildcard: https://answers.sap.com/questions/7850575/crystal-report---using-wild-characters-in-selectio.html